# How to simultaneously animate a cell and table change in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to simultaneously animate a custom UITableViewCell and the UITableView that contains it.

When clicked, the subviews of the UITableViewCell slightly re-arrange such that the height of the cell increases. I want the re-arrangement within the cell to happen concurrently with the resizing of the UITableView's slot for that cell, so that it doesn't overlap with the cell below it.

When clicked again, the reverse is to happen.

This is what I've tried so far.

#### The UITableView

When the UITableView is clicked, I use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to update a `selectedPath` property:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (self.selectedPath && indexPath.row == self.selectedPath.row) {
            self.selectedPath = nil;
        } else {
            self.selectedPath = indexPath;
        }
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Note, it calls `reloadData`, which triggers each visible cell to re-fetch the prototype and configure it based on whether it is selected or not:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    QueueItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"QueueCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    if (self.selectedPath && indexPath.row == self.selectedPath.row) {
        [cell makeSelected:YES];
    } else {
        [cell makeSelected:NO];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
    CGFloat height = 210;
    if (indexPath.row == [self.imageList count] - 1) {
        height += 10;
    }
    if (self.selectedPath && indexPath.row == self.selectedPath.row) {
        height += 35;
    }
    return height;
}
```

#### The UITableViewCell subclass

In the custom cell class, its animation happens when it is made selected or not selected:

```
- (void)makeSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    if (selected) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.customImage.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 210);
        }];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.customImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 200);
        }];
    }
}
```

#### What is happening

The table view immediately snaps to the new the allotted height for the cell, and then the cell's contents slowly animate to the new state. I want the two things to happen concurrently, and smoothly.

Comment: You need to reload all the cell or particular cell animation while you tap the cell

Comment: I am reloading all cells. See `[tableView reloadData]`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}];
```

and re-write the custom cell as following:

```
- (void)makeSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    if (selected) {
         self.customImage.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 210);
    } else {
         self.customImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 200);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, because the thing that is being "animated" is a reload of data. From the viewpoint of the UITableView, that is not actually something that can be animated. It is simply a few calls to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, etc. What happens when I use this suggestion is that both the table update and the cell update happen instantly, rather than smoothly.

Comment: I see...Sorry for not being able to help but there isn't a way I know of that can change the height smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

You need to reload particular cell while tap use like this..

```
- (void)makeSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    if (selected) {
         self.customImage.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 210);
    } else {
         self.customImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 200);
    }
}
```

Declare `BOOl isSelect;` as Global

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            if (self.selectedPath && indexPath.row == self.selectedPath.row) {
               isSelect = NO;
            } else {
                self.selectedPath = indexPath;
                isSelect = YES;
            }
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates]; 
       }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    QueueItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"QueueCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    if (self.selectedPath && indexPath.row == self.selectedPath.row && isSelect) {
        [cell makeSelected:YES];
    } else {
        [cell makeSelected:NO];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
    CGFloat height = 210;
    if (indexPath.row == [self.imageList count] - 1) {
        height += 10;
    }
    if (self.selectedPath && indexPath.row == self.selectedPath.row && isSelect) {
        height += 35;
    }
    return height;
}
```

It reload the cell with animation.. I hope it will help you.. Now you check it will work as you want...

Comment: This causes a non-smooth jump when deselecting the cell. It immediately snaps the cell contents to be smaller (while leaving an artifact behind from the larger cell contents), then follows up with a smooth animation of the table to the smaller height, cleaning up the artifact that was left behind. See http://imgur.com/0GHNLwc

Comment: @Jared: Can you share your code bcoz you need like that means.. You have boolean value in self for this.. It will make smooth as you want..

Comment: How did you test this code? It isn't any different from your first edit. `BOOL isSelect` is simply doing the same work as checking that `self.selectedPath` isn't equal to `nil`.

Comment: Why you didn't got your solution huh?

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work. The animation is not smooth. No part of this code lets me control how smooth the animation is. It has the same problems as I described before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060395/how-to-simultaneously-animate-a-cell-and-table-change-in-ios/28060585?noredirect=1#comment44502567_28060585

Answer (score 0):

try this... reload particular cell insteade

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedRowIndexPath inSection:section];
// Add them in an index path array
NSArray* indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath1, nil];
// Launch reload for the two index path
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: This was suggested already by TamilKing (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060395/how-to-simultaneously-animate-a-cell-and-table-change-in-ios/28060585#28060585). It doesn't give a smooth animation.